# Combine Two Datasets from Different Selects into One Table in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: dataset, reportbuilder

Can report builder 3.0 combine data from two datasets into one table?

I have scanned other questions here and found nothing with info relating to report builder directly.  Most examples are C# code, but I am using report builder only.  Can report builder do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the UNION function?  You should be able to use that between the SELECTs to bring back both together.

Comment: I cannot do that.  My selects are based upon a where clause using the a date files.  Each column needs to be base upon a different month. for example: "SELECT
  TPMmonthly.SVID
  ,TPMmonthly.AirportID
  ,TPMmonthly.ADSBUATOnlinePct
  ,TPMmonthly.ADSBUATDegradedPct
  ,TPMmonthly.ADSBUATOfflinePct
  ,TPMmonthly.ADSBUATAvailTimePct
FROM
  TPMmonthly
WHERE
  TPMmonthly.reportdate = (@EndDate)
ORDER BY SVID"

Comment: Are both of your selects pulling the same columns but from different tables?  And is the where clause the same for both select statements?

Comment: I would try putting a UNION after the "WHERE TPMmonthly.reportdate = (@EndDate) ORDER BY SVID", and then start your next SELECT.  It should work if you are selecting the same columns from different places.